# EditText with phone number that has a dash

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How can I include a dash after the 3rd and 6th digit from a phone number and also how can I delete that dash if I press backspace? I am assuming that i have to use:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher);
```

Can someone help me with this?
This is not a duplicate question cause the one you have shown me dose not cover the deletion of the dash. If you copy that code and try it, you will see that if you press backspace after you have more than 3 digits, the cursor will freeze before the dash.

Comment: yes, you need to use textwatcher

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of what you have just shown. That code is inserting a dash in a phone number, but not deleting it when I press backspace. If you copy that code, when you press backspace after you have more than 3 digits, you cursor will stop before the dash.

Comment: try this, `TextWatcher textWatcher=new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}@Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {e.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                    if(s.length()==3||s.length()==7)
                        e.setText(s+"-");
                    e.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            }@Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        };`

Comment: Who is "e" and who is "textWatcher"?

Comment: e is your edittext and, use this textwatcher as, editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

Comment: Ok. Now I see. But i have the same problem. If i press backspace(on a virtual keyboard) the cursor stops at the dash character.